# Specifying compiler versions in travis for cmake builds

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang, travis-ci

The travis [Building a C++ Project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/cpp/) documentation shows how to specify gcc and clang compiler versions in build matrices. However, it does *not* show how to build projects with those compilers using cmake.

I amended the `.travis.yml` file [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/blob/master/.travis.yml) to specify gcc 9 and clang 8 as per the travis documentation, i.e.:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-9
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc-9 && CXX=g++-9"

    - compiler: clang
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
            - llvm-toolchain-bionic-8
          packages:
            - clang-8
            - libstdc++-8-dev
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang-8 && CXX=clang++-8"

before_install:
  - eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"
  - pip install --user cpp-coveralls
...

script:
  - mkdir _builds
  - cd _builds
  - cmake -DVIA_HTTPLIB_UNIT_TESTS=ON -DVIA_HTTPLIB_COVERAGE=ON ${CMAKE_OPTIONS} .. 
  - make
  - ./via-httplib_test
```

But is caused build errors when running `cmake`, e.g.:

```
$ cmake -DVIA_HTTPLIB_UNIT_TESTS=ON -DVIA_HTTPLIB_COVERAGE=ON ${CMAKE_OPTIONS} ..
CMake Error at /usr/local/cmake-3.12.4/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  gcc-9.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/travis/build/kenba/via-httplib/_builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
The command "cmake -DVIA_HTTPLIB_UNIT_TESTS=ON -DVIA_HTTPLIB_COVERAGE=ON ${CMAKE_OPTIONS} .." exited with 1.
```

I tried fixing the errors by specifying `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` for cmake, but I could not get it to work. 
However, it builds correctly with:

```
  env:
    - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc && CXX=g++"
  ...
  env:
    - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang && CXX=clang++"
```

but builds with the default [bionic](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/bionic) `gcc` and `clang` compilers, i.e.: GCC 7.4.0 and Clang 7, *not* GCC 9 and Clang 8.

How to write a `.travis.yml` file so that `cmake` can find and use 
the compiler versions specified in a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was a Travis issue? Simply adding the [g++-9 package and changing the variable to MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc-9 && CXX=g++-9"](https://github.com/JanSimek/via-httplib/commit/5630d819f38c09d121a1d2821dbea6ee0e069d8d) results in a successful [compilation of your project with GCC 9.3.0](https://travis-ci.com/github/JanSimek/via-httplib/jobs/326471968)

This is a minimal example that I use for building my project:

```
language: cpp

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test'
          packages:
            - clang-8
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang-8 CXX=clang++-8"
    - os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test'
          packages:
            - g++-9
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc-9 CXX=g++-9"

before_install:
  - eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"

script:
  - cmake .
  - make
```